# Known that: $3pq-5p+4q=22$, Find the value of $p + q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have this question:

> > Known that:
> >     $$3pq-5p+4q=22$$
> >     Find the value of $p + q$

I have solved 2 variables with 2 equations or more, but I have never encountered 1 equation with 2 variables. The answer is a positive integer. Can I have a hint or a guide?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the nature of $p,q$

Comment: Are $p$ & $q$ integers?

Comment: Yes, they are integers

Comment: @A---B When you spot an obviously errorneously used tag, you can just remove it (possibly but not necessarily also add a more appropriate one). Well spotted anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given equation can be written as
$$(3p+4)(3q-5)=46$$
Since $p$ and $q$ are both integers (as what OP has mentioned in the comments). Therefore, we want factors of $46=ab$ such that 
\begin{align*}
3p+4 & =a \\
3q-5 & =b
\end{align*}
Thus
$$3(p+q)=a+b+1 \implies a+b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$$
But the only possible values for $a,b \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 23, \pm 46\}$ (of course with $ab=46)$. However the solutions that satisfy $a+b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ are $(a,b) \in \{(1,46), (46,1),(-2,-23),(-23,-2)\}$.

Hence $p+q \in \{16,-8\}$.

Comment: the rhs should be $46$, not $86$.  In that case there are solutions, like $(14,2)$.

Comment: @themaker I have fixed the error. It should be $16$ and $-8$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with $3$, add a constant term and factorize to get
$$
(3p+4)(3q-5)=3(3pq−5p+4q)-20=46
$$

If the quadratic equation $$0=z^2-az+46$$ has the solutions $z_1=(3p+4)$, $z_2=(3q−5)$ then by the Viete rules $$a=z_1+z_2=(3p+4)+(3q−5)=3(p+q)-1$$ which is independent of the order of the roots.

As $46=z_1·z_2=1·46=2·23=(-2)·(-23)=(-1)·(-46)$ only has that many integer factorizations, one quickly finds the only solutions 
\begin{align}
3(p+q)-1&=47:&p+q&=16;\\
3(p+q)-1&=25:&not~&possible\\
3(p+q)-1&=-25:&p+q&=-8\\
3(p+q)-1&=-47:&not~&possible\\
\end{align}

Comment: if you multiply by $3$, the right side is $66$, not $46$. See my solution.

Comment: Yes, and $66-20=46$. You need to do both, multiply with 3 *and* factorize, to get that result, as you did (but somehow got a sign wrong).

Comment: you are right my mistake. Thanks,